# Create api not create a form for sample JSON for picture choice rest of all working fine

Tags: typeform

Create api not create a form for sample JSON for picture choice rest of all working fine

```
{
      "ref": "nice_readable_picture_choice_reference",
      "title": "Picture Choice Title",
      "type": "picture_choice",
      "properties": {
        "description": "Cool description for the picture choice",
        "randomize": true,
        "allow_multiple_selection": false,
        "allow_other_choice": true,
        "supersized": false,
        "show_labels": false,
        "choices": [
          {
            "ref": "foo_choice_ref1",
            "label": "Foo 1",
            "attachment": {
              "type": "image",
              "href": "https://images.typeform.com/images/4bcd3"
            }
          },
          {
            "ref": "foo_choice_ref2",
            "label": "Foo 2",
            "attachment": {
              "type": "image",
              "href": "https://images.typeform.com/images/4bcd3"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "validations": {
        "required": false
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain what your problem is? It's really hard to understand.

Comment: I am creating the form from Create API. Sample JSON api provided by typeform all field create the form but picture_choice sample JSON not create the form. Reast all the field create the form sample JSON.